Can a laptop have more than one HDMI port?
Can laptop have more than one HDMI port?
My laptop has one HDMI I wish it had one more so that I can connect a 3rd monitor.
Is it possible to have one more HDMI port on my existing laptop?

Do you mean in general? Or for your specific laptop model?

Out of the box: do you want more HDMI, or more monitors? Your laptop might very well have other useful ports (e.g. USB-C with display out. Or in the case of the laptop on which I am typing this: 2x DP, 1xHDMI, 1xUSB-C, but with a max of 4 screens at the same time. So adding a 4th would disable the internal screen).  Do the extra screens need to have some performace, or it is enought o just display email, excels etc etc.  And did you consider a docking station? Those often have 2-3 monitor ports, usually at least one with HDMI.

Yes, you can have more than one HDMI port. You mentioned you already have two HDMI ports and they are being used. It is very dependent on your laptop, but you can use USB-C-to-HDMI adapter to get your third HDMI monitor.
Looks like this:
USB-C / Type C to HDMI (4K@30Hz) + VGA (1080P) Adapter

Or if you don't have any USB-C ports, then use this type of model USB-A 3.0:
StarTech.com USB to HDMI Adapter - External Video Card - USB 3.0

If you haven't guessed, your laptop must support either/or USB 3.0 A-type or USB-C.
Additionally, if you can get one of these adapters — don't start gaming on the third monitor — the graphic lagging is very bad.

I tried connecting the second monitor via usb 3 hdmi adapter but the monitor lags a lot sometimes it freezes and I read few answers which says it is normal, but if you could let me know which laptop model has more than one hdmi port

@Rakeshvalappil Laptops with more than one HDMI port are quite unusual but in miniPCs (essentially the same hardware) that's very common. This answer assumes you have an USB-C port with alt video mode. That not being the case you're left with monitor adapters like DisplayLink and those have some limitations indeed. No, you can't add an additional video output to a laptop.
